# jQuery: using regex to find selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to find a selector that looks like `color-1` or `color-99`. The word "color" followed by a hyphen followed by one or two digits of any value.

The REGEX is completely escaping me, and it's pissing me off. Here's what I have:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        //stuff to do when mouse enters
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        //stuff to do when mouse leaves
    }
}, ".color-\\S*")
```

As it is, it only finds one-digit selectors like `color-1` or `color-9`.

If I make the last bit `".color-\\d\\d"` it finds "color-22" and other two-digit colors.

---

Things I've tried that don't work:

`".color-[1-9][0-9]?"`

`".color-[0-9]{1,2}"`

`".color-\\d+"`

`"a[class|='color']"`

`"a[class^='color-']"`

How do I do this? Here is a fiddle demonstrating. Right now, I am using two selectors to find everything, but that sort of defeats the point of regex, doesn't it?

https://jsfiddle.net/q17fg3y5/

Comment: I'm surprised `"a[class^='color-']"` did not work, or did it match too much?

Comment: You really shouldn't do this. Give them all *one* CSS class, and then add the number as a data attribute.

Comment: @meagar each class has a purpose. It represents a different color from the theme. There are multiple instances of each color and I want to highlight all of the series when I hover over one specific instance. A data attribute won't help me here.